# Generate page with inline JS and CSS with Rails

Tags: assets, rails-3.1

I'm using Rails 3.1. My JavaScript and CSS files are included in usual way:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Now I want to create standalone version of existing page with default layout. I want it to be a single html file that user can download and use in offline. So, JavaScript and CSS code must be included in content of this file. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? I'm in the same situation right now, and google is not giving me any love ;)

Comment: Not yet, but I didn't try hard.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate CSS and JS and include them in config.assets.precompile key in the file config/application.rb.

Check this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets)